# Error: The GitHub Action workflow must specify exactly one of "workload_identity_provider" or "credentials_json"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions

`Error: Action failed with error: Error: The GitHub Action workflow must specify exactly one of "workload_identity_provider" or "credentials_json"!`

My GHA yaml code:

```
steps:
  - name: git checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - id: auth
    name: Authenticate to Google Cloud
    uses: google-github-actions/auth@v0.4.0
    with:
      credentials_json: '${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_DEV_2 }}'
```

This used to work with `credentials_json: '${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}'`

I dont know why changing secrets name could affect the authentication

Error snapshot in GHA:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 2 GHA files.
Main file and `workflow_call` file .
I was changing secret name in this `workflow_call` file from       `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_DEV_2`

But I wasn't making the same change in the input for `workflow_call` file:

```
on:
  workflow_call:
    secrets:
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:
        required: true
```

Hence it would work when I used `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` everywhere and did not work as soon as I changed it to `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_DEV_2`